# Numeros aleatorios en c#

Tags: c#

Se que existe la clase `Random`, pero busco una forma de generar números cleatorios de una mejor manera, ya que como dice en la documentación de Microsoft,

> Representa un generador de números pseudoaleatorios

¿Alguien conoce otras maneras de generar números aleatorios?

Resuelto:
He consegido resolver mi problema aplicando un tiempo de espera en la consola con

> Thread.Sleep(15);

Como Random trabaja con el relog del sistema si se usa la instancia solo asi, al hacer cientos de operaciones por milisegundo la computadora, proboca que genere el mismo numero varias veces, al hacer esperar unos milisegundos se generan numeros diferentes

Comment: No es posible que un computador genere números realmente aleatorios, o al menos no se ha descubierto todavía. No se que es lo que necesitas, pero creo que `Random` debería ser suficiente.

Comment: ¿Para qué tipo de aplicación necesitas los números "aleatorios"?

Comment: Quiero hacer un programa con el que se generen numeros al azar (o algo parecido). El problema con Random es que tengo entendido genero los numero con el relog del sistema, y al ser muy rapida las operaciones por segundo, se "genera" el mismo numero miles de veces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Alguien conoce otras maneras de generar números aleatorios?

Esta pregunta conceptual, no está ligada a C# como lenguaje, así que la respuesta tampoco.

---

Los ordenadores no pueden generar números aleatorios, se basan en algoritmos para generar números con apariencia de aleatoriedad, esto se conoce como [números pseudo-aleatorios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_pseudoaleatorio):

> *Un número pseudo-aleatorio es un número generado en un proceso que parece producir números al azar, pero no lo hace realmente. Las secuencias de números pseudo-aleatorios no muestran ningún patrón o regularidad aparente desde un punto de vista estadístico, a pesar de haber sido generadas por un algoritmo completamente determinista, en el que las mismas condiciones iniciales producen siempre el mismo resultado*.

Sin embargo, a pesar de que existen [múltiples algoritmos para generar números pseudo-aleatorios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators), dado que (con mayor o menor dificultad) se puede deducir la secuencia generada, se estudian otros métodos para generar números realmente aleatorios como [escuchar el "*ruido*" del sistema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) o incluso obtener datos atmosféricos.